# oracle pl/sql input error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

**Code:**

```
DECLARE
 N NUMBER :=&N;
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(N);
END;
```

**Error:**

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 12: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&"
>   when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current
>   exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge
>   time timestamp interval    date       pipe

Comment: May I know the IDE you are working with?

Comment: oracle 10g sql command

Comment: Did you try set define on;

Answer (score 3):

You need to do:

```
SET DEFINE ON
```

I think you are using GUI client like **SQL Developer**, and you do not have define on. `&` is used for a **substitution variable**.

In **SQL Developer:**

```
SET serveroutput ON
SET define OFF
DECLARE
  N NUMBER :=&N;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(N);
END;
/

Error starting at line : 8 in command -
DECLARE
  N NUMBER :=&N;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(N);
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 14:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an alternatively
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Set define on, and try again:

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> SET DEFINE ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    N NUMBER :=&N;
  3  BEGIN
  4    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(N);
  5  END;
  6  /
Enter value for n: 10
old   2:   N NUMBER :=&N;
new   2:   N NUMBER :=10;
10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Its work successfully in SQL developer but it not working in oracle 10g "sql commands". Its says missing or invalid option.

Comment: i can not define it proprly but it run in browser which 10g express edition and its "SQL commands " named where execute sql query.

Comment: You must tell what exactly you are doing. Which client you are using? At least, tell us if you know about the client?

Comment: oracle 10g express edition and i write command in sql commands which open in browser (firefox,chrome etc.).